# SQL Server and NoSQL interactions

Tags: sql, join, nosql, sql-server-2012

I have a table A that contains 500,000 rows. Table is related with 5 other tables (B,C,D,E,F) (the size of 100,000 rows each).

I'd like to extract in a fast way a structured information as (key A, value A+B+C+D+E+F) where value A+B+C+D+E+F is the column result of inner join of these 6 tables (bit slowly).

On these tables updates/insert/delete occur every 10 min (asynchronously).

I need to present result of this selection to perform a search as a binding source.

**My IDEA**

Materialize this selection in a NoSQL database where to perform search. My questions is:

- which NoSQL database to use?
- how to synchronize SQL Server to change the data in the NoSQL database any time my SQL Server record is changed?

*SCENARIO*

- Desktop application made by C# and framework 4.0
- Database SQL Server 2012

Comment: *Why* do you want to use Nosql? 500,000 is neither here nor there for a properly designed database.

Comment: To experiment NoSQL database and then because I think it lends itself well in these conditions.